# Could someone explain this autohotkey script to me?

Tags: autohotkey

It's supposed to let me turn a toggle a run button on and off in a game (instead of having to hold it down). It works, but I'd like to know **how**.

```
$w:: Gosub, AutorunToggleME2
~s:: Gosub, AutoRunOffME2

AutorunToggleME2:
toggle := !toggle
Send % "{w " . ((Toggle) ? ("down") : ("up")) . "}"
return

AutoRunOffME1:
toggle = ; Off
Send {w up}
return
```

Specifically, I'd like what the following lines do:

```
Send % "{w " . ((Toggle) ? ("down") : ("up")) . "}"

Send {w up}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is pretending to hold down <kbd>w</kbd>. The basic `Send` syntax is explained [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm).

> To hold down or release a key: Enclose in braces the name of the key
>   followed by the word Down or Up. For example:
>
> ```
> Send {b down}{b up} 
> Send {TAB down}{TAB up} 
> Send {Up down}  ; Press down the up-arrow key. 
> Sleep 1000  ; Keep it down for one second. 
> Send {Up up}  ; Release the up-arrow key.
> ```

So this line:

```
Send {w up}
```

Clearly is releasing <kbd>w</kbd>.

The other line is more complicated:

```
Send % "{w " . ((Toggle) ? ("down") : ("up")) . "}"
```

You can find explanations of the relevant syntax [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Variables.htm).

Basically:

- `%` says that the following text is an *expression*.
- The `.` is a string-concatenation operator.
- This part `((Toggle) ? ("down") : ("up"))` is the conditional operator (a.k.a ternary operator). It's shorthand for an `if/else` statement. In this case, when `Toggle` is true, it returns "down", otherwise it returns "up".

This works out to either `Send {w down}` or `Send {w up}` depending on the value of `Toggle` (true or false)